# Access SQL - Results contain values when I have a Is Null criteria

Tags: ms-access

I'm scratching my head and I'm looking for suggestions for what might be causing it.

The following sql returns an unexpected result. One record is being displayed that has a populated Date_File_Complete and I can't work out why.
It's something to with the join as the erroneous result is not show when I remove the join.

```
SELECT Case.TID, Case.File_Complete, Case.Date_File_Complete, Notes.Status
FROM Case LEFT JOIN Notes ON Case.TID = Notes.TID
WHERE (((Case.Date_File_Complete) Is Null) AND ((Case.Assigned_To)="User A"));
```

I've drawn a blank and I can't work out what might be causing it to appear.

Thanks

- Removing the join results in the record not being displayed - great but now I don't have all the data I need.
- Switching the where to use File_Complete does the same but this is one of a several reports that would need to be re-written but that's just a work around and wouldn't align with the current indexing.

edit: added "where to use File_Complete"

Comment: Debug your data. There is no way a record can come out with a field not being _Null_ if this is filtered to be _Null_. Not sure what _Switching the criteria_ means, though.

Comment: @Gustav sorry, that wasn't clear. I meant switching from Date_File_Complete to using File_Complete both will be null

Comment: OK. But again: If you filter for "Is Null", no value can be present.

Comment: agreed, but it does and I'm not sure why a join would break that principal.

Comment: If File_Complete is a yes/no field then it cannot be null. File_Complete field is redundant. If there is value in Date_File_Complete then the file is complete. You might have to provide db for analysis as something is wrong with your data and likely cannot replicate that with a posted sample. Might want to post in a form that allows attaching files. Have you tried Compact & Repair?

Comment: Hi All, thanks for the feedback. We had some downtime yesterday so I was able to do a compact and repair on the master database and this resolved the issue. Not sure why but it did.

Answer (score 0):

Ran compact and repair on the backend database and this resolved the issue.